# send a http request based on a route with expressJS and RequestJS

Tags: node.js, http, express, requestjs

I am trying to send a HTTP request using RequestJS when a route is called with ExpressJS. My goal here is to resolve the HTTP request with Request first, and then return the result on route call. I am getting an error. But it seems not to be working.

Please help. Here is my code:

```
var express  = require('express');
var apiRoutes = express.Router();
var request = require('request');

//Require our Report Model
var Report = require('./models/report');


apiRoutes.get('/', function (req,res) {
    res.json({Message: 'Welcome To Reported API. Start Interacting With Our Endpoints'});
});

apiRoutes.get('/reports', function (req,res) {
    request('http://www.google.com', function(err, res, body){
        if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)//Show HTML from Google
        }
    })
});

module.exports = apiRoutes;
```

Comment: It would be helpful to actually include the error you are getting. Also, if you're just proxying, you should pipe between the upstream and downstream connections instead of using the callback-based `request()`, which buffers the upstream response.

Comment: 'res' in the callback; s duplicated, please rename to other name